# i18n / Markdown - Does Markdown support internationalization?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, internationalization, markdown

I'm building a CMS which needs to manage content in english, chinese, and spanish at a minimum. Do most markdown implementations handle UTF-8 encoded text? Is the Markdown language designed to be used with non-english languages? I'm currently using Markdown Extra by Michel Fortin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown is languages neutral so you can use it easily as it does not care about encoding
as long as ASCII is a subset of it.

However I would not recommend you using smarty-pants as they designed for English so you may get incorrect quotes in your language.

Answer (score 1):

As Michel Fortin (a french speaking guy), I use his library (the extra one) with special characters like éà without any problem